# Asp.net redirect to bank sms verification (3DPay) page after form post

Tags: c#, asp.net, bank, form-post, sms-verification

I am trying to create credit card payment page.
I am posting the form in code behind (C#) and successfully get the verification sms from bank.
But it does not redirect to bank sms verification page so there is no where to enter verification code.
So what should i do?

```
Here is my code under the Pay button:
   String shopCode = "SHOPCODE";
        String purchaseAmount = "ORDER PRICE";
        String currency = "CURRENCY";
        String orderId = "ORDERID";
        String okUrl = "REDIRECT PAGE AFTER SMS VERIFICATION COMPLETED SUCCESSFULLY";
        String failUrl = "REDIRECT PAGE IF SMS VERIFICATION FAILS";
        String rnd = DateTime.Now.ToString();

        String installmentCount = "3";
        String txnType = "txnType";
        String merchantPass = "merchantpass";
        String str = shopCode + orderId + purchaseAmount + okUrl + failUrl + txnType + installmentCount + rnd + merchantPass;

        System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1 sha = new System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
        byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-9").GetBytes(str);
        byte[] hashingbytes = sha.ComputeHash(bytes);

        String hash = Convert.ToBase64String(hashingbytes);

        String cardnumber = "CREDIT CARD NUMBER";
        String expiry = "EXPIRY DATE";
        String CVCCVV = "CVCNUMBER";
        String securetype = "3DPay";
        String lang = "language";

        ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
        string postData = "Pan=" + cardnumber;
        postData += ("&Expiry=" + expiry);
        postData += ("&Cvv2=" + CVCCVV);
        postData += ("&ShopCode=" + shopCode);
        postData += ("&PurchAmount=" + purchaseAmount);
        postData += ("&Currency=" + currency);
        postData += ("&OrderId=" + orderId);
        postData += ("&OkUrl=" + okUrl);
        postData += ("&FailUrl=" + failUrl);
        postData += ("&Rnd=" + rnd);
        postData += ("&Hash=" + hash);
        postData += ("&TxnType=" + txnType);
        postData += ("&InstallmentCount=" + installmentCount);
        postData += ("&SecureType=" + securetype);
        postData += ("&Lang=" + lang);

        byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(postData);

        HttpWebRequest myRequest =
          (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("POSURL");
        myRequest.Method = "POST";
        myRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        myRequest.ContentLength = data.Length;
        Stream newStream = myRequest.GetRequestStream();

        newStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        newStream.Close();
```

EDIT:
It works fine if i do it in client (html) side, but i want to do it in server side.

Answer (score 0):

we need json information from the bank

```
try
{
   HttpClient clients = new HttpClient();
   clients.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);
   HttpResponseMessage _response = await clients.GetAsync("banksmspage");
   _response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
   string responseBody = await _response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
   dynamic json = JObject.Parse(responseBody);
   string smscode = json.jsontitle.smscode;
    
   if (smscode != null)
   {
    if (smscode == UsersmsEnterString)
    {
       Response.Redirect("BankpageURL");
    }
    else
    {
       Response.Redirect("ErrorURL");
    }
   }
  }
 catch {}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. Yes we need but it does not already redirected to bank sms verification page to enter sms code on. That is the problem. After sms verification completed successefully it redirects to OkUrl, if fails, it redirects to fail url. there are okurl and failurl parameters in posted data.

Comment: sorry i didn't understand the problem, if you share the full codes i can help further

Comment: What response is received from the bank when you post this information?

Comment: please add newStream response

Comment: I am getting the verification sms from bank successfully. But it should redirect bank sms verification page to enter the verification code after i have posted the form. But there is no redirection to the bank sms verification page. This is the problem. When i do tht in html side, it works great, and redirect to the bank sms verification page,  but not redirect in server side.

Comment: then you are sending incomplete or incorrect, you need to debug the "postData" data first.

Comment: No it is absoultely correct, if it is not correct then i could not get the sms code.

Comment: Don't you send a post to send the sms code again after the sms code is received?

Comment: It should redirect to the bank page to enter sms code. But there is no redirection. this is the problem